# How do I set up a Tor server?

Tags: apache2, mysql, php, tor

I would like to host a tor hidden services website (aka .onion site) on my Ubuntu desktop with the LAMP stack installed.

While [the tor docs](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-hidden-service.html.en) offer some guidance on running an anonymous server, the directions are pretty vague.

It's the second paragraph of "step one: install a web server locally" I'm unclear about.

So, bind my web server to localhost. Check, I did that by editing the apache2 config file to only listen on `127.0.0.1:80`.  I also made sure MySQL was also bound to `127.0.0.1` too.

What else should I do?
What error messages should I edit?
Is there anything in my PHP installation I should edit?
I'll also be running wordpress. Anything to be concerned with there?
Finally I have installed `nikto` to scan for vulnerabilities. Are there any tests or parameters I should include given this is a tor hidden service?

Comment: If you want to make sure there is no identity leak you could consider using an isolated network system like Whonix: https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Main_Page otherwise make sure your webserver is only reachable via localhost using iptables.

Comment: awesome! perfect! thank you! that's exactly what i was looking for :)  an os built to run tor and host hidden services...amazing!  i wish i could mark your comment as an answer.  thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Unless the Tor guides specify not to do so, I'd recommend using nginx over Apache for pretty much anything these days.

While your machine is connected to your LAN, you can check it using another machine.  From another machine on your LAN, use `sudo nmap -p- IP.TO.TOR.HOST`.  You can then see what ports are visible, pretty much like an attacker would do.

Comment: thanks for the tip.  i hadn't heard of nginx, so it was cool to read up on it.  i think because  my web site doesn't have scalability concerns, i'll stick with apache since i'm familiar with it.  unless i'm missing something about nginx that would help me with my concerns about remaining anonymous?

Comment: The nginx comment was completely a personal preference.  Stick with what you feel comfortable with, but I bet you'll be using nginx eventually ^_~.